# How can I get rid of the "move to applications" window?

Tags: finder

[image]

A few weeks ago I downloaded Brackets from the internet. Now whenever I turn on my computer, I see the following popup and nothing I have tried will make it go away. Can anyone explain what this is, why it pops up, and what I can do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

It's a mounted Disk Image [.dmg]

You should be able to right-click inside that window [over some empty space] & "Eject Brackets Release 1.14".

It should then not re-mount automatically. You can also simply discard the .dmg file once you've installed the app, by dragging to your Applications folder as indicated.

Any Application delivered by this method should be run only after copying to Applications & not from the mounted Disk Image itself. If it is running from the image, it will not let you eject.

Comment: I have tried ejecting and dragging multiple times without success. Also, when I drag "Brackets Release 1.14" from my desktop to my trash can, it reappears on my desktop within 30 seconds.

Comment: Make sure that the application is not running.

Comment: Have you rebooted since? Are you trying to actually run the App from the .dmg rather than from Applications? Apps are not supposed to run from the image, though some will.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but as an aside, the entire DMG workflow might make a lot more sense if you remember that software used to come on CDs. So you'd insert a CD that you bought at CompUSA or whatever, and a Finder window would pop up saying "Drag this app to your applications folder". DMGs originated to provide a virtual equivalent of CDs, and like CDs, they should be ejected once you're done with them.